# GWT & Thymeleaf & Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, gwt, thymeleaf

I have a problem integrating this two technologies.

We have an GWT application integrated with Spring but, additionally to GWT application we need to display HTML files using Thymeleaf for special modules.

The GWT application works well but when I try to run it with Controllers and Thymeleaf enabled this fail.

I've added this to my web.xml to support the Spring Controllers use:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/spring/controller-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And my **controller-context.xml** has this beans:

```
    <bean id="uiengineTemplateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/uiengine/target/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolvers">
            <array>
                <ref bean="uiengineTemplateResolver"/>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And this at the end:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.enterprise.platform.*.gui" />
```

There is a way to integrate this two frameworks?

I'll appreciate your help!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved!

First you need to exclude the main HTML file for GWT from ThymeleafViewResolver so:

**controller-context.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="excludedViewNames">
            <array>
                <value>gwt-project.html</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Allow the static access for the resources of GWT application:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/gwt-project/**" location="/gwt-project/" />
```

Create a Spring Controller with access root method:

**MyController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{appBeanId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String root(@PathVariable String appBeanId, Locale locale,
                org.springframework.ui.Model model) {

        ....
    }
}
```

That's it!.